# Xcode 7.3.1: No matching provisioning profiles found for application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assets

I read all the similar questions in stackoverflow and cant solve my problem.
I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I am trying to upload an update of my existing app to iTunesConnect but I always get this warning.

No matching provisioning profiles found for application. None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active, apps-enviroment.

I have deleted all my developer certificates and provisioning profiles in Developer console and created again but the problem is not solved.

I also followed this tutorial to allow Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html, but the problem is not solved.

Maybe any sugestion? I have this problem by more than a week.

Comment: select Xcode preference and go to "Accounts" Tab.check whether any accounts configured  in Accounts Tab if not configure your account.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my developer account is already registered in "Accounts" Tab.

Comment: Then select your account. press "View Details.." button and download your required provisioning profile. and restart Xcode.

Comment: I did it again, and then select my developer profile in "code signing", then archive the app and when trying to upload to iTunes Connect I get the same error.

Comment: Download iphone configuration utility and manage your provisioning profile or else just regenerate provisioning file in your developer account

Comment: In rare cases I have seen that provisioning profiles do not change in the pbxproj file which is located in `YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. Try to search for these artifacts which have key `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "";` Maybe the error message is misleading.

Comment: @midori I found six keys PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "", what should I change there?

Comment: @datha I open iPhone Configuration Utility and found all my provisioning profiles, what should I change there?

Comment: @jlandyr ok this looks good. If there was an artefact there would be the a number as value of the key which is not the case. In your case it is empty. One more thing which comes in my mind - you said you deleted all the certificates from Apple Member Center - delete all Provisioning Profiles in `/Users/user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and only download the one Provisioning Profile you need.